# Getting P-Values of Zero in Cox Regression: R

Tags: r, bioinformatics, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I am a student conducting a gene expression survival analysis in R. I have the expression data for 249 patients, and I am using 6,000 genes as well as their event-free survival times and vital state as response variables. When I tried to run the Cox regression on my dataset, I got extremely strange results (p-values of 0.00 and strange hazard ratios). I have checked over my code multiple times, but I am not able to catch my mistake (when I tried earlier with just one gene, it worked fine, but when I try to test multiple genes using the '.' function, I am not getting porper results). I would highly appreciate any help and have attached both my code and output! Let me know if more information is needed.

```
library(survival)
options(expressions = 5e5)
firstSplitData <- read.delim("/Users/menon/OneDrive/Desktop/csrsef files/FirstSplitDataFrame.txt")
firstInitialData <- data.frame(firstSplitData)
firstEventFreeTime <- firstInitialData[ , c("EFST")] 
firstVitalStatus <- firstInitialData[, c("Status")]
#create a temporary object to use in the final object in order to be able to use '.'
temporaryObj <- Surv(as.numeric(firstEventFreeTime), firstVitalStatus == 2)
firstFinalData <- data.frame(SurvObj = temporaryObj)
#bind the two together for the final data 
firstFinalData <- cbind(firstFinalData, firstInitialData[, 2:ncol(firstInitialData)])
#create final cox model
firstCox <- coxph(SurvObj ~ ., data =  firstFinalData)
summary(firstCox)$coefficients
```

And here is (some of) my output:

```
> summary(firstCox)$coefficients
                     coef     exp(coef)     se(coef)             z      Pr(>|z|)
EFST         3.644083e-03  1.003651e+00 0.0001340611    27.1822581 1.052851e-162
Status      -2.926090e+00  5.360625e-02 0.3182658189    -9.1938542  3.790122e-20
AADACL3      1.502153e+02  1.728460e+65 0.3665374081   409.8224582  0.000000e+00
AADACL4      5.857192e+01  2.738174e+25 0.3681708023   159.0889828  0.000000e+00
ACADM        2.455978e+02 4.589695e+106 0.2175220391  1129.0710334  0.000000e+00
ACAP3        4.093913e+02 6.256964e+177 0.2756635268  1485.1121632  0.000000e+00
ACOT11       1.940976e+01  2.688751e+08 0.3251033140    59.7033512  0.000000e+00
ACOT7       -2.841794e+02 3.823403e-124 0.3139848504  -905.0736377  0.000000e+00
ACTB        -5.562202e+01  6.976896e-25 0.3173481100  -175.2713234  0.000000e+00
ACTL8       -4.017414e+02 3.356676e-175 0.3435128215 -1169.5093020  0.000000e+00
ACTRT2      -7.613568e+01  8.603881e-34 0.2861088372  -266.1074036  0.000000e+00
ADC         -1.244476e+02  8.976070e-55 0.3201452217  -388.7223972  0.000000e+00
ADPRHL2      4.887427e+01  1.681998e+21 0.2895110526   168.8165913  0.000000e+00
AGMAT        7.266946e+02           Inf 0.4295874196  1691.6104194  0.000000e+00
AGO1         3.352041e+02 3.778188e+145 0.2633158947  1273.0111995  0.000000e+00
...
```

And here is what `dput(firstFinalData[1:10, 1:10])` produces:

```
structure(list(SurvObj = structure(c(444, 5553, 5296, 922, 205, 
47, 401, 245, 263, 5564, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), .Dim = c(10L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("time", "status")), type = "right", class = "Surv"), 
    EFST = c(444L, 5553L, 5296L, 922L, 205L, 47L, 401L, 245L, 
    263L, 5564L), Status = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L), AADACL3 = c(5.52132, 5.64712, 5.45876, 5.71481, 
    5.1269, 5.88764, 5.08912, 4.91729, 5.65387, 5.59824), AADACL4 = c(5.17251, 
    5.41843, 5.10969, 5.23402, 4.60353, 5.70923, 5.02245, 5.1466, 
    4.8355, 4.83986), ACADM = c(7.47834, 7.43494, 7.91155, 7.86337, 
    8.39009, 6.16251, 7.83793, 7.71742, 6.98061, 7.78087), ACAP3 = c(7.80589, 
    8.00354, 7.75014, 7.61566, 7.55267, 7.9449, 7.20561, 7.99776, 
    7.72778, 7.43355), ACOT11 = c(6.75915, 6.30386, 6.38214, 
    6.54392, 6.64743, 6.78981, 6.42641, 6.58761, 6.66693, 6.53731
    ), ACOT7 = c(8.11807, 8.38011, 7.8349, 8.43645, 8.11502, 
    8.0109, 7.6866, 8.55327, 8.17004, 7.44455), ACTB = c(10.8227, 
    11.4556, 11.4216, 11.332, 10.9536, 9.83797, 11.2352, 11.5006, 
    11.1817, 10.895)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thank you so much!

Edit:

I also get this warning message when I run `firstCox <- coxph(SurvObj ~ ., data =  firstFinalData)`:

```
In fitter(X, Y, istrat, offset, init, control, weights = weights,  :
  Ran out of iterations and did not converge
```

Comment: You've got way too many commands than are necessary. After importing the data, you can just run the model. See my answer below. Put the `Surv()` function directly inside the call to coxph. R knows not to include the outcome in the `.`.

Comment: Oh, I just realised that you probably wanted to run multiple regressions, one for each gene. Is that correct? You threw me with the `coxph(SurvObj ~ ., data =  firstFinalData)` command because the `.` indicates that you want to run a multivariate model, which is impossible here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to perform multiple Cox regression models with a single predictor, you could use the following code using your posted example data. First I remove the survival object in the first column.

```
myData <- finalData[,-1]

library(survival)
firstCox <- co

coxph(Surv(EFST, Status) ~ ., data =  myData)
```

## This returns a warning as stated (too many predictors)

```
Warning message:
In fitter(X, Y, istrat, offset, init, control, weights = weights,  :
  Ran out of iterations and did not converge
```

To run multiple univariate models, first create a list of univariate formulas:

```
formulas <- sapply(names(myData)[3:9], function(x) as.formula(paste('Surv(EFST, Status) ~ ',x)))
```

Create a list of models using the `coxph` function:

```
models <- lapply(formulas, function(x) coxph(x, data=myData))
```

Extract the hazard ratios (`exp(coef)`) and 95% confidence intervals:

```
res <- lapply(models, function(x) return(cbind(HR=exp(coef(x)), exp(confint(x)), Pval=coef(summary(x))[5])))
res
```

---

```
$AADACL3
               HR       2.5 %   97.5 %     Pval
AADACL3 0.1858129 0.008579879 4.024119 0.283442

$AADACL4
               HR      2.5 %   97.5 %      Pval
AADACL4 0.8481017 0.02748128 26.17333 0.9249839
...
```

Comment: Sorry for all the questions - I would also like to extract the p-values using this code, and was trying to apply summary() to my models list object in order to get the p-value, but I am instead receiving something that looks like this:         GIPC2       19     coxph list
GJA9.MYCBP  19     coxph list
GLTPD1      19     coxph list
… If this is not the appropriate place to ask this question, I will gladly move it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Just add: `, Pval=coef(summary(x))[5])` after `exp(confint(x))`.

Comment: Hello Edward, Thank you so much once again!

Comment: @AnkitaM can you show me the your actual dataframe how you constructed that would be really helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

Except for the first two coefficients (`EFST` and `Status`), the coefficients for all other genes are either extremely small or extremely large, leading to very large negative/positive *t*-statistics, which explains the p-values you're seeing.

I'm not exactly sure I understood what you're doing. Wouldn't regressing on 6,000 genes in your 249 patients data mean that you're having way more parameters than observations?

In which case, you're running into overfitting issues which would explain the parameter estimates.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the response - I have the gene expression data for 249 patients of 23,000 of their genes, and I am trying to run a Cox regression on 6,000/23,000 of their genes (testing each gene individually) by using event-free survival time and vital status. Do I have a fundamental misunderstanding in what I am trying to do? I was under the assumption that since I am testing each gene separately, I would not run into any issues. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Hi Ankita. Still not sure I fully understand what you're doing. That aside, testing each gene separately is generally not a good idea; you'd run into multiple testing issues and generally wouldn't be able to (meaningfully) compare results. After all, isn't the whole point of your work to assess the effect of different genes on the patient survival? Secondly, in the formula expression `SurvObj ~ .` the right-hand side expands to *all* variables/columns that are not included in the left hand side. So you are in fact regressing on all 6000 genes in one model (not separately)

Comment: I am trying to find survival related biomarkers, and so I want to test each gene individually against the event-free survival time and the vital status (I did this already once with a gene that I had a hypothesis about and it worked, but I would like to do this for all 23,000 genes). However, I wasn't sure how to do this simultaneously in R other than to use the '.' function, but I now realize that this would entail testing the genes together and not separately.

Comment: No, I don't think it's statistically sound/valid to test genes individually, as you would ignore all confounding effects from all the other genes. That's a very slippery slope, which may lead to non-interpretable results at best, and cherry-picking at worst.

Comment: Ok, I see. I based my original procedure/project off of this post I saw - https://www.biostars.org/p/344233/ - but I realize that I now might have to change some things. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @AnkitaM I had a read through the Biostars post. TBH I'm sceptical whether this is a statistically sound approach. Doing so many multiple tests (of potentially correlated predictors) gets you into murky waters, where you'd have to somehow correct for multiple hypothesis testing. I second Edward's suggestion to talk to a resident (bio)statistician.

Answer (score 0):

Don't include the Surv() object in the data frame.

```
firstFinalData <- firstFinalData[,-1]
firstCox <- coxph(Surv(EFST, Status) ~ ., data =  firstFinalData)
```

It should work (**edit**: on a smaller number of variables).

As Maurits Evers says, running a model with 6,000 predictor variables (genes) on only 249 subjects will result in convergence problems. Consider reducing the number of genes (or obtaining more patients!)

Comment: Not sure if this will work. I may have misunderstood, but OP seems to have 6,000 regressors (genes) but only 249 observations (patients). This sounds like an ill-posed problem to me, which will lead to overfitting without some form of regularisation (or some informative/regularising priors on the parameters in a Bayesian framework).

Comment: I agree. I was merely pointing out the superfluous commands, and specifically that the `Surv` object should NOT be included in the data frame since R will attempt to include all other variables in the `.`, and the data that OP `dput`ted contained too many variables. Look at the output. EFST and Status are included as predictors!

Comment: Thank you both for the response. Even if I am testing the genes individually, does this cause problems merely because I am testing 6,000 genes with 249 patients? I am not really sure I understand this because I was able to successfully obtain Cox regression results when testing the genes individually and one-by-one (opposed to having the program do it all at the same time).

Comment: That is not a coding question. My answer fixed your coding problems. I suggest you ask modelling questions in another post, or elsewhere, or consult a qualified statistician.

Comment: @Edward *"Look at the output. EFST and Status are included as predictors!"* Yeah, you're correct in fixing OPs syntax. This seems to be a multiple-factorial problem (coding syntax and stats).

Comment: Agreed. Unfortunately I don't have the solution on how to predict survival using 6,000 genes for only 249 patients. Machine learning? I'm only guessing. Perhaps data mining to find which genes are predictive _on their own_ and then confirm these results on another group of patients. Hypothesis testing is not data mining.